# load an external js, when moving to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this button :

```
<a onclick="return false;" href='javascript:(function(){s=document.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.src="http://localhost/demogen/demogen.js";document.body.appendChild(s);})();' class="Button">siteDEMO < /a>
```

that users can drag to their browser's toolbar, and when they go to their website, by clicking on the button on the toolbar, it loads demogen.js script.

Now I want to add an event that when this script is loaded in a page, and the user clicks on a link, when browser moved to next page, load the script for that page again.
any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the url of the js in the url of the next page.

i.e:

```
var jsURL = '/demogen/demogen.js',
    nextURL = 'nextPage.html?js=' + encodeURIComponent(jsURL);
```

Then in the next page retrieve the js path by:

```
var jsURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(4));
```

To finally load the script in the next page inserting a SCRIPT tag in the HEAD or BODY with it's src attribute pointing to the jsURL value

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with a bookmarklet.  Bookmarklets load these scripts for the current page by actually injecting a `<script>` tag into the DOM.  This script that's been injected is only able to live within the page its been injected into.